# Questions about default applications in ElementaryOS Juno

Tags: elementary-os, editors, text, defaults

I know this title seems a bit recurrent, but after several hours of search, I still don't understand.

Basically, what I want to do is set Sublime Text as default text editor. Each time I see a valid answer to this question, I'm told to check in *Properties* (of a specific file) to chose the default app. Or, to directly change the default app for *text editor* in the settings.  However, two problems show up :

1) First (it's a bit subjective but I'm convinced most of you would agree with me), I would be surprised to know that the easier way to change a text editor is to set the default app **for every format individually**.

2) When I try the solution explained above, Sulbime Text doesn't appear.

Though, I saw some changes I could bring to `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` or `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` but I have to admit I didn't understand everything. Moreover (I don't know if what I'm going to say even makes sense), when I open this file and look for lines that begin with `text/` it is written `gedit.desktop` whereas the default text editor on ElementaryOS is Code.

Does anyone can explain me what is the purpose of this file ? And eventually how may i set Sublime Text as a default text editor ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: While your question is definitely acceptable in U&L, have you considered https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @garethTheRed I looked for a stack exchange for elementaryOS but didn't find it. You're right. I might ask there if I get no answers here. As you said, I think this section is still appropriate.

Comment: Followed by: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7707/how-do-i-set-gvim-as-the-default-editor-in-loki

Comment: Nothing of these instructions helped me out. Some friend told me that it becomes quite complicated when it comes to set off a .exe as a default app. I think I'm just gonna use another text editor...